# For Loop Correlation Test in R

Tags: r, correlation

I wanted to run a for loop to do multiple correlation tests on my dataframe. There is also NA's in my dataframe so I wanted to omit as well!

This is part my dataframe. It is much more extensive but a snippet of it is easier to understand.

```
name: carsdataframe
      price      mph      maxmph      model year      status
1      NA        60        100          2013          1
2      NA         57        96          2019          0
3      5.2        52        NA          2017          1
```

I want to do the I currently have:

```
for (i in c(1:4)){
    colcor <- colnames(carsdataframe[i])
    coresult <- cor.test(carsdataframe$colcor,carsdataframe$"status",use="pairwise.complete.obs")
    finalcor <- c(coresult, colcor)
}
colcor
```

However this code does not work and I am greeted with "'x' and 'y' must have the same length." I was wondering how do I code for it. What should I fix?

Sorry if I am making amateur mistakes, I just started using R! Thanks you in advance! :)

```
carsdataframe <- structure(list(price = c(NA, NA, 5.2), mph = c(60L, 57L, 52L), 
    maxmph = c(100L, 96L, NA), model_year = c(2013L, 2019L, 2017L
    ), status = c(1L, 0L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: Would you mind posting a sample of your data (i.e. total and carsdataframe) using the output of dput? It would be esier to help that way.

Comment: Hi, sorry about that I made a mistake in the original post! I think it is fixed now, I am so sorry.

Comment: You can only use object names with `$` so you need to use `carsdataframe[, colcor]` because `colcor` contains the name of the column you want. It is not the column you want. Since 'status' is the name of the column you want, use `carsdataframe$status`. Do not put the name in quotations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the column name is stored in a variable don't use `$`, use `[[` to extract the column values as vector. You can use `lapply` which is similar to `for` loop.

```
list_data <- lapply(names(carsdataframe), function(x) 
  cor.test(carsdataframe[[x]],carsdataframe$status,use="pairwise.complete.obs"))
```

You can use `sapply`/`lapply` to extract specific statistics. For eg - to get `p.value` you can do :

```
sapply(list_data,`[[`, 'p.value')
#Or
#sapply(list_data,function(x) x$p.value)
```

---

To calculate correlation between every combination of variable you can calculate `list_data` as :

```
list_data <- combn(names(carsdataframe), 2, function(x)  
 cor.test(carsdataframe[[x[1]]],
          carsdataframe[[x[2]]],use="pairwise.complete.obs"), simplify = FALSE)
```

Comment: Got it! Thanks! I was wondering if I wanted to find the correlation between each of the variable to the others, what would I do. This would mean I would be finding the correlation between price v.s. mph, price v.s. maxmph, price v.s. model year, mph v.s. maxmph, etc. Am I able to replace the $status with [[x]]? Once again, thanks a lot for the help already!

Comment: That is a different question than what you had originally asked. It should be asked as a new question but since you are new to the platform I have edited the answer to include it. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Sorry about that. Got it! Thank you so much for the help. I really appreciate it!